# SubQuery and ROWNUM in MySQL : SELECT * FROM (SELECT...)

Tags: mysql, subquery, row-number

*EDIT: This solved my problem:*

```
select id_t,punctaj 
from test 
where punctaj in (select punctaj from test ) 
order by punctaj desc 
limit 1;*
```

I have written a working Oracle SQL code but when I'm trying to convert it to MySQL I have a syntax error which I cannot solve. It looks like MySQL does not accept ROWNUM and also SELECT * FROM a subquery. What could be the solution? I need the biggest value of "PUNCTAJ" from the tests and I need to keep that "IN". Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
select* from (
select id_t,punctaj
from test
where punctaj in (select punctaj from test ) 
order by punctaj desc)
where rownum<=1
```

error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where rownum<=1 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6

Comment: And the exact error that you receive is?   Can you add some sample data, and desired output?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+top-n

Comment: Thanks! Got it solved

Answer (score 0):

you have written twice the where condition,
In secondd where use AND rownum<=1